# .load() looses the hierarchy of loaded html elements

Tags: jquery

I have almost solved my task to partial load a html with jquery (1.8.0).

This is the html I would receive from my server:

```
<form id="save-form" action="/sales_item/edit/9/" method="post">
  <p>
     <label for="id_item_description">Item Description:</label>
     <input id="id_item_description" type="text" maxlength="40" value="test2y" name="item_description">
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

However when I load the above with the following jquery in my `<tr>` element...

```
function row_edit() {
    // e.g. url = '/sales_item/edit/8' 
    var url = $(this).attr("href") + "/";

    //e.g. get whole row to be replaced with editing fields
    var row = $(this).closest('tr')

    row.load(
        url,        
        function () {
            $("#save-form").submit(url, row_save);
        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

, the hierarchy is completely lost, see how form tag is closed before the content.

```
<tr>
   <form id="save-form" action="/sales_item/edit/9/" method="post"></form>      
   <p>
     <label for="id_item_description">Item Description:</label>
     <input id="id_item_description" type="text" maxlength="40" value="test2y" name="item_description">
   </p>
   <input type="submit" value="save">
</tr>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong in my load?

Comment: A table row can only contain table cells. I'm not sure if that causes the issue, though. (Try wrapping the form in a `<td>` first.)

Comment: This is the answer my friend. Thank you. :) Please insert it so I can tick it off.

Comment: I did it like this: `var target = $('<td></td>').appendTo(row)` and then `target.load(...)` is this a good approach?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I came up with as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<tr>` cannot contain `<form>` elements. Most browsers try to solve it to a certain extent, but it's not reliable, and it's plainly invalid after all.

You'd need to create a `<td>` first:

```
$("<td>").appendTo(row).load(...);
```

Comment: I also realized the content of tr needs to be wiped for the purpose of the partial loading. `var row = $(this).closest('tr').empty();` :)